# Why does my function in R keep reading my argument as a function?

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

When I create a user-defined function in RStudio, or even just have a for loop, it keeps returning this error:

```
    p <- NEQ1data$P.inv.
    for(value in p){
    sem <- sqrt(value(1-value)/10000)
    return(sem)
    } 
    Error: could not find function "value"
```

Similarly, when I try a to define this function:

```
    se_fyp <- function(a){
    sem<-sqrt(a(1-a)/10000) 
    return(se)
    }
```

And have the input "NEQ(1)$P.inv." it says that it cannot find "function a".

I'm teaching myself R, and have yet to find any information on this issue.I believe that I am following the standard function format.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can leave out the `*` in maths notation but not in most programming languages (certainly not in R).

Comment: Ahh such a silly mistake! Thank you for you help!

Comment: can you give us an example of what there is in p? p <- NEQ1data$P.inv.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
sqrt( value( 1-value ) / 10000)
```

You're trying to call `value` like a function. Look at the similarity to the call to `sqrt`. I added spacing here for emphasis.

No language that I know of allows for "implicit multiplication". You need to explicitly write the `*`

```
sqrt( value * ( 1-value ) / 10000)
```